# Boost asio error with Cygwin

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, cygwin, boost-asio

I am getting some weird errors trying to compile a program that uses boost.asio. I just download/compiled the library so maybe there was an error during that?
I am using gcc, and cygwin on windows 
The program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io;

  boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
  t.wait();

  std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Trying to compile gives me this error message:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/async_result.hpp:18:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio.hpp:20,
                 from test.cpp:27:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/config.hpp:566:5: warning: #warning Please define _WIN32_WINNT or _WIN32_WINDOWS appropriately. [-Wcpp]
 #   warning Please define _WIN32_WINNT or _WIN32_WINDOWS appropriately.
     ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/config.hpp:567:5: warning: #warning For example, add -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 to the compiler command line. [-Wcpp]
 #   warning For example, add -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 to the compiler command line.
     ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/config.hpp:568:5: warning: #warning Assuming _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 (i.e. Windows XP target). [-Wcpp]
 #   warning Assuming _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 (i.e. Windows XP target).
     ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/config.hpp:592:5: error: #error You must add -D__USE_W32_SOCKETS to your compiler options.
 #   error You must add -D__USE_W32_SOCKETS to your compiler options.
     ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/posix_tss_ptr.ipp:24:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/posix_tss_ptr.hpp:76,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/tss_ptr.hpp:27,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/call_stack.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/impl/handler_alloc_hook.ipp:19,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/handler_alloc_hook.hpp:80,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/handler_alloc_helpers.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/bind_handler.hpp:19,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/wrapped_handler.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/io_service.hpp:24,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_io_object.hpp:19,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio.hpp:21,
                 from test.cpp:27:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/error.hpp:87:31: error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression
       BOOST_ASIO_NATIVE_ERROR(ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE),
                               ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/error.hpp:140:31: error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression
       BOOST_ASIO_NATIVE_ERROR(ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY),
                               ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/error.hpp:145:31: error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression
       BOOST_ASIO_NATIVE_ERROR(ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED),
                               ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/error.hpp:153:31: error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression
       BOOST_ASIO_NATIVE_ERROR(ERROR_BAD_UNIT),
                               ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/error.hpp:164:31: error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression
       BOOST_ASIO_NATIVE_ERROR(ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED),
                               ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/error.hpp:178:31: error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression
       BOOST_ASIO_NATIVE_ERROR(ERROR_RETRY),
                               ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/socket_types.hpp:38:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp:22,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/winsock_init.hpp:125,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/io_service.hpp:28,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_io_object.hpp:19,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio.hpp:21,
                 from test.cpp:27:
/usr/include/w32api/winsock2.h:1004:68: error: conflicting declaration of C function ‘int gethostname(char*, int)’
   WINSOCK_API_LINKAGE int WSAAPI gethostname(char *name,int namelen);
                                                                    ^
In file included from /usr/include/wchar.h:4:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/include/c++/cwchar:44,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/include/c++/bits/postypes.h:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/include/c++/iosfwd:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/include/c++/ios:38,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from test.cpp:26:
/usr/include/sys/unistd.h:249:6: note: previous declaration ‘int gethostname(char*, size_t)’
  int _EXFUN(gethostname, (char *__name, size_t __len));
      ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/winsock_init.hpp:125:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/io_service.hpp:28,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_io_object.hpp:19,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio.hpp:21,
                 from test.cpp:27:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp: In static member function ‘static void boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::startup(boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::data&, unsigned char, unsigned char)’:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp:36:44: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedIncrement(volatile int*)’
   if (::InterlockedIncrement(&d.init_count_) == 1)
                                            ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp:40:45: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedExchange(volatile int*, int)’
     ::InterlockedExchange(&d.result_, result);
                                             ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp: In static member function ‘static void boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::manual_startup(boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::data&)’:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp:46:44: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedIncrement(volatile int*)’
   if (::InterlockedIncrement(&d.init_count_) == 1)
                                            ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp:48:40: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedExchange(volatile int*, int)’
     ::InterlockedExchange(&d.result_, 0);
                                        ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp: In static member function ‘static void boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::cleanup(boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::data&)’:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp:54:44: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedDecrement(volatile int*)’
   if (::InterlockedDecrement(&d.init_count_) == 0)
                                            ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp: In static member function ‘static void boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::manual_cleanup(boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::data&)’:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp:62:40: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedDecrement(volatile int*)’
   ::InterlockedDecrement(&d.init_count_);
                                        ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp: In static member function ‘static void boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::throw_on_error(boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::data&)’:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp:67:55: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedExchangeAdd(volatile int*, int)’
   long result = ::InterlockedExchangeAdd(&d.result_, 0);
                                                       ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/impl/io_service.hpp:69:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/io_service.hpp:767,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_io_object.hpp:19,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio.hpp:21,
                 from test.cpp:27:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/win_iocp_io_service.hpp: In member function ‘bool boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::stopped() const’:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/win_iocp_io_service.hpp:84:49: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedExchangeAdd(volatile int*, int)’
     return ::InterlockedExchangeAdd(&stopped_, 0) != 0;
                                                 ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/win_iocp_io_service.hpp: In member function ‘void boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::reset()’:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/win_iocp_io_service.hpp:90:39: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedExchange(volatile int*, int)’
     ::InterlockedExchange(&stopped_, 0);
                                       ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/win_iocp_io_service.hpp: In member function ‘void boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::work_started()’:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/win_iocp_io_service.hpp:96:46: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedIncrement(volatile int*)’
     ::InterlockedIncrement(&outstanding_work_);
                                              ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/win_iocp_io_service.hpp: In member function ‘void boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::work_finished()’:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/win_iocp_io_service.hpp:102:50: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedDecrement(volatile int*)’
     if (::InterlockedDecrement(&outstanding_work_) == 0)
                                                  ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/win_iocp_io_service.hpp:310:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/impl/io_service.hpp:69,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/io_service.hpp:767,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_io_object.hpp:19,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio.hpp:21,
                 from test.cpp:27:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.hpp: In member function ‘void boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::schedule_timer(boost::asio::detail::timer_queue<Time_Traits>&, const typename Time_Traits::time_type&, typename boost::asio::detail::timer_queue<Time_Traits>::per_timer_data&, boost::asio::detail::wait_op*)’:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.hpp:94:45: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedExchangeAdd(volatile int*, int)’
   if (::InterlockedExchangeAdd(&shutdown_, 0) != 0)
                                             ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.hpp: In member function ‘std::size_t boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::cancel_timer(boost::asio::detail::timer_queue<Time_Traits>&, typename boost::asio::detail::timer_queue<Time_Traits>::per_timer_data&, std::size_t)’:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.hpp:114:45: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedExchangeAdd(volatile int*, int)’
   if (::InterlockedExchangeAdd(&shutdown_, 0) != 0)
                                             ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/win_iocp_io_service.hpp:312:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/impl/io_service.hpp:69,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/io_service.hpp:767,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_io_object.hpp:19,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio.hpp:21,
                 from test.cpp:27:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp: In member function ‘void boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::timer_thread_function::operator()()’:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp:51:63: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedExchangeAdd(volatile int*, int)’
     while (::InterlockedExchangeAdd(&io_service_->shutdown_, 0) == 0)
                                                               ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp:56:66: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedExchange(volatile int*, int)’
         ::InterlockedExchange(&io_service_->dispatch_required_, 1);
                                                                  ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp: In member function ‘virtual void boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::shutdown_service()’:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp:93:38: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedExchange(volatile int*, int)’
   ::InterlockedExchange(&shutdown_, 1);
                                      ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp:102:56: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedExchangeAdd(volatile int*, int)’
   while (::InterlockedExchangeAdd(&outstanding_work_, 0) > 0)
                                                        ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp:112:50: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedDecrement(volatile int*)’
         ::InterlockedDecrement(&outstanding_work_);
                                                  ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp:125:50: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedDecrement(volatile int*)’
         ::InterlockedDecrement(&outstanding_work_);
                                                  ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp: In member function ‘size_t boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::run(boost::system::error_code&)’:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp:153:53: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedExchangeAdd(volatile int*, int)’
   if (::InterlockedExchangeAdd(&outstanding_work_, 0) == 0)
                                                     ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp: In member function ‘size_t boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::run_one(boost::system::error_code&)’:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp:172:53: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedExchangeAdd(volatile int*, int)’
   if (::InterlockedExchangeAdd(&outstanding_work_, 0) == 0)
                                                     ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp: In member function ‘size_t boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::poll(boost::system::error_code& ’:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp:187:53: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedExchangeAdd(volatile int*, int)’
   if (::InterlockedExchangeAdd(&outstanding_work_, 0) == 0)
                                                     ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp: In member function ‘size_t boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::poll_one(boost::system::error_code&)’:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp:206:53: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedExchangeAdd(volatile int*, int)’
   if (::InterlockedExchangeAdd(&outstanding_work_, 0) == 0)
                                                     ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp: In member function ‘void boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::stop()’:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp:221:41: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedExchange(volatile int*, int)’
   if (::InterlockedExchange(&stopped_, 1) == 0)
                                         ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp:223:53: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedExchange(volatile int*, int)’
     if (::InterlockedExchange(&stop_event_posted_, 1) == 0)
                                                     ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp: In member function ‘void boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::post_deferred_completion(boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_operation*)’:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp:247:49: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedExchange(volatile int*, int)’
     ::InterlockedExchange(&dispatch_required_, 1);
                                                 ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp: In member function ‘void boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::post_deferred_completions(boost::asio::detail::op_queue<boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_operation>&)’:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp:268:51: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedExchange(volatile int*, int)’
       ::InterlockedExchange(&dispatch_required_, 1);
                                                   ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp: In member function ‘void boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::abandon_operations(boost::asio::detail::op_queue<boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_operation>&)’:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp:279:46: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedDecrement(volatile int*)’
     ::InterlockedDecrement(&outstanding_work_);
                                              ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp: In member function ‘void boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::on_pending(boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_operation*)’:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp:286:53: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedCompareExchange(volatile int*, int, int)’
   if (::InterlockedCompareExchange(&op->ready_, 1, 0) == 1)
                                                     ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp:295:51: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedExchange(volatile int*, int)’
       ::InterlockedExchange(&dispatch_required_, 1);
                                                   ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp: In member function ‘void boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::on_completion(boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_operation*, DWORD, DWORD)’:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp:319:49: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedExchange(volatile int*, int)’
     ::InterlockedExchange(&dispatch_required_, 1);
                                                 ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp: In member function ‘void boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::on_completion(boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_operation*, const boost::system::error_code&, DWORD)’:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp:341:49: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedExchange(volatile int*, int)’
     ::InterlockedExchange(&dispatch_required_, 1);
                                                 ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp: In member function ‘size_t boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::do_one(bool, boost::system::error_code&)’:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp:350:63: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedCompareExchange(volatile int*, int, int)’
     if (::InterlockedCompareExchange(&dispatch_required_, 0, 1) == 1)
                                                               ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp:399:57: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedCompareExchange(volatile int*, int, int)’
       if (::InterlockedCompareExchange(&op->ready_, 1, 0) == 1)
                                                         ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp:434:51: error: cannot convert ‘long int*’ to ‘volatile int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int _InterlockedExchange(volatile int*, int)’
       ::InterlockedExchange(&stop_event_posted_, 0);
```

The error goes on a bit longer, but SO limits the number of characters in a post 
I've been stuck on this and am not sure how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:
I compiled with the windows flags added as kenba suggested. However the same error is appearing, without those warnings at the top.
Perhaps relevant: I tested a couple of other Boost libraries and they work fine, the problem seems to be with asio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by removing my build of boost, and using the cygwin installer to build it instead. Not sure why that was happening, but for anybody using cygwin and boost, I would recommend using the installer.

Answer (score 0):

`asio` needs to know what version of `Windows` it's being built for, so you need to set the macro `_WIN32_WINNT`, see [Using the Windows Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa383745(v=vs.85).aspx). For example, adding the following to the compile command sets `NTDDI_VERSION` and `_WIN32_WINNT` to the values required for Windows 7`:

```
-DNTDDI_VERSION=NTDDI_WIN7 -D_WIN32_WINNT=_WIN32_WINNT_WIN7
```

Also note that although `boost asio` itself is a header only library, it needs to be linked to the `boost` `system` library, so the link command will require something like:

```
-LC:\boost\boost_1_60_0\stage\lib -lboost_system-mgw49-mt-1_60
```

Depending upon where you've built the boost libraries and which version of `boost` and `gcc`/`mingw` you are using.